# "Bad data .\r\n" Error for RSA signing data

Tags: c#, encoding, rsa, signing

This question might be duplicate but other solutions seem to be not working for me. I am working on RSA for the first time, so little confusing. I have public and private keys and want to sign the text using these. Below is my code:

```
public void RSA()
{
    var publickey = "***";
    var privatekey = "***";
    using (var RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
                UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
                RSAParameters myRSAParameters = RSA.ExportParameters(true);
                myRSAParameters.Modulus = ByteConverter.GetBytes(publickey);
                myRSAParameters.D = ByteConverter.GetBytes(privatekey);
                myRSAParameters.Exponent = ByteConverter.GetBytes("5");
                string signedmessage = SignData("ABC", myRSAParameters);
     }
}

 public static String SignData(string message, RSAParameters privatekey)
 {
            byte[] signedBytes;
            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
                byte[] originalData = encoder.GetBytes(message);

                try
                {
                    rsa.ImportParameters(privatekey);
                    signedBytes = rsa.SignData(originalData, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA512"));
                }
                catch (CryptographicException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    return null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
                }
            }

            return Convert.ToBase64String(signedBytes);
 }
```

Actually I am not sure about RSAParameters they are given correctly or not. After running this code this throws an exception as

> "Bad data .\r\n"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If importing a private key you need to specify all the parameters. Your code has the public key from one key, a D value which is probably ignored by the underlying system, and PQ != Modulus. That may not be the only problem, but it’s certainly not helping.

Comment: Sorry but I am not cleared with what data is needed for what parameter. I just know till this that Modulus is for the public key, D is for the private key and for rest I am searching.